# Whose Idol is this?

Tags: shiva, temple, identification-request

[image]

[image]

In the Sri Sri Taraknath temple,Tarakeswar, West Bengal (a very very famous Shiva Temple of Bengal), an idol with two hands holding a trident is seen just beside the anadi-linga of Baba Taraknath.

So far as my limited knowledge goes, no dhyana-mantra of Lord Shiva depict Him as two handed like this. Also, Lord Shiva is generally not worshipped with the red 'Jaba' flower as shown in the photograph.

Could someone identify this idol with proper scriptural reference?

Comment: I think this is Lord Vishnu

Comment: It's lord Shiva visit [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taraknath_Temple) or [Dept. of Tourism Gov. ot WB site](https://wbtourismgov.in/destination/details/tarakeshwar)